# Spring Cloud Zookeeper - override default registration process

Tags: spring, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, service-discovery

The [documentations](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-zookeeper/1.1.1.RELEASE/#_registering_with_zookeeper) states that

> The default service name, instance id and port, taken from the Environment, are ${spring.application.name}, the Spring Context ID and ${server.port} respectively.

Is there a hook which can be used to override this behavior -
registering a different server and port value?

e.g. there is the `EurekaClientConfigBean` which be used with Spring Cloud Eureka to achieve the same result.

Comment: There are properties you can set. I'm on a mobile or I'd point you to them.

Comment: I see. Isn't there a programmatic way to achieve this ?

Comment: ZookeeperDiscoverProperties is the configuration object

Comment: thanks @spencergibb ! it worked.. minor correction - its `ZookeeperDiscoveryProperties`